# Overflow to left and top?

Tags: css

If an element has `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll`, and its contents overflow, then scrollbars are shown... but only if the content overflows to the right or off the bottom.

Is it possible for the `overflow` to apply scrollbars if content is overflowing to the left, or off the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask is somewhat contradictionary. If you want to show the whole content of a larger box inside a smaller box, you must have a scrollbar position for each side's end. When you place content (with absolute position and/or negative margins) which overflows this "endpoint" in either direction, you essentially block yourself from using the scroll feature as it is intended to be. (this does not mean that I do not find it usefull sometimes :)

Answer (score -1):

If content is overflowing to the left or to the top, then both scroll bars appears with `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/4d6f2/)

With `overflow: scroll` scroll bars are always visible, even if content does not overflow.

With `overflow: auto` scroll bars are visible, only when content does overflow.

Comment: It didn't post my comment >_> I downvoted because your answer isn't really relevant. I know how `overflow` works, but what I'm talking about is if the content actually goes into negative coordinates relative to the container. Sorry for not making sure the comment got posted correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. Next time, include that kind of information in your question.

Comment: @Kolink This answer is correct, regardless the fact that does not address entirely your problem, in part because your question was not clear to begin with. I think that downvoting it is inappropriate.